# Почему не работает команда man -k [любое слово]?

Tags: linux, man

При попытке использовать команду

```
man -k time
```

Получаю...

```
time: nothing appropriate.
```

Помогите, я не понимаю что происходит...

Comment: может самих манов нету ? пакет `man-db` или как-то так

Comment: Если я правильно понял вас, то команда <man time> - выполнится как положено, откроется страница с описанием, и любой другой мануал можно посмотреть, к любой команде. А вот командой как в вопросе - ожидаю увидеть список команд, где используется "time", но ничего не получается. Не могу понять, в чем причина

Comment: попробуйте тогда обновить индексы командой `mandb -c`

Comment: вот это помогло. Спасибо большое! Храни вас Господь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
sudo mandb
```

На крайний случай

```
sudo mandb -c
```

Comment: Да, это то что нужно было. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Рад был помочь :) (если не жалко, можете пожалуйста пометить решением?)